# mysql counting rows with loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+-------------+--------------+ 
| product     | purchased    |
+-------------+--------------+ 
| Hammer      | <timestamp>  |
| Nipper      | <timestamp>  |
| Saw         | <timestamp>  |
| Nipper      | <timestamp>  |
| Hammer      | <timestamp>  |
| Hammer      | <timestamp>  |
| Saw         | <timestamp>  |
| Saw         | <timestamp>  |
| Saw         | <timestamp>  |
+-------------+--------------+
```

I would like to see a summary about the warranty status of these products. The Warranty should be 5 years from the purchase date. So with the date of today it should be possible to check if a product is under warranty or not (base on the purchase date). Also I would like to now when the last bought product will be out of warranty. Here is a example table:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| product     | count        | warranty valid | warranty expired | last p. warranty |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| Hammer      | 3            | 1              | 2                | 10.03.2015       |
| Nipper      | 2            | 2              | -                | 01.01.2014       |
| Saw         | 4            | 1              | 3                | 02.12.2013       |
+-------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I tried to create the query for this example, but I didn't know how to loop the results for every product to count valid warrantys and so on. That's what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT
    product,
    date_format(from_unixtime(purchased), '%d.%m.%Y') AS purchaseDate,
    date_format(date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), '%d.%m.%Y') AS warrantyEnd,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(product)
        FROM
            productWarranty
    ) AS count
FROM
    productWarranty s
GROUP BY
    product
```

I don't know how to write the subquery because, I need to use something like WHERE product = Hammer. But how can I tell sql to loop for every single product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer I posted in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582967/how-to-handle-large-mysql-queries/19583193?noredirect=1#comment29066588_19583193)

```
SELECT  p2c.pid AS productNumber,
        p.name AS productName,
        COUNT(*) AS registered,
        SUM(date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) >= CURDATE()) AS inWarranty,
        SUM(date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) < CURDATE()) AS outOfWarranty,
        DATE_FORMAT( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), '%d.%m.%Y') AS lastPurchased,
        DATE_FORMAT( date_add( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), '%d.%m.%Y') AS warrantyUntil
FROM products2customers p2c
JOIN products p ON p.id = p2c.pid
GROUP BY p2c.pid
ORDER BY inWarranty DESC
```

Comment: Thanks again Mr. Barmar. :) Hope to see you in future questions. ;-) Have a nice Day.

Comment: I know that the OP asked you to post this here, but your answer does not answer the stated question (there's no mention of joins). Renaud's is essentially the same as yours but more appropriate to this particular question.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to work with is whether the warranty is still valid or expired and the warranty date, so you first need to build a table that reflects that:

```
select   product
       , IF( warranty >= NOW(), 1, 0 ) as valid
       , IF( warranty < NOW(), 1, 0 ) as expired
       , warranty as last
from     (
           select   product
                ,   ADDDATE( purchased, INTERVAL 5 YEAR ) as warranty
           from     productWarranty
         ) w
group by product
;
```

That would get you something like that:

```
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| product | valid | expired | warranty            |
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| Hammer  |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Nipper  |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Nipper  |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Nipper  |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Saw     |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Saw     |     0 |       1 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Saw     |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Saw     |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

Then use aggregate functions to filter and sum up the information you're looking for:

```
select   product
       , SUM( IF( warranty >= NOW(), 1, 0 ) ) as valid
       , SUM( IF( warranty < NOW(), 1, 0 ) ) as expired
       , MAX( warranty ) as last
from     (
           select   product
                  , adddate( purchased, interval 5 year ) as warranty
           from productWarranty
         ) w
group by product
;
```

```
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| product | valid | expired | last                |
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| Hammer  |     1 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Nipper  |     3 |       0 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
| Saw     |     3 |       1 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------+-------+---------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Better [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) would speed up this query tremendously, but here's an example to work from:

First, you need to start with your base query, the one that will drive the results. In this case, it's a list of all the products in your table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product
FROM   productWarranty
```

The above query creates a sort of "temp" table that we can base our queries on. If you have a separate, normalized product table then that would be much better.

The rest of the columns can simply be subqueries driven by your base table:

Total count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   productWarranty
WHERE  product = 'Hammer'
```

Total valid warranties:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   productWarranty
WHERE  product = 'Hammer'
   AND purchased >= <warranty cut-off date>
```

Total expired warranties:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   productWarranty
WHERE  product = 'Hammer'
   AND purchased < <warranty cut-off date>
```

Last purchase date:

```
SELECT MAX( purchased )
FROM   productWarranty
WHERE  product = 'Hammer'
```

Now to combine all of these into a single query:

```
SELECT  Base.product
    ,   (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   productWarranty
            WHERE  product = Base.product
        ) AS TotalCount
    ,   (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   productWarranty
            WHERE  product = Base.product
               AND date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) >= CURDATE()
        ) AS ValidWarrantyCount
    ,   (    
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   productWarranty
            WHERE  product = Base.product
               AND date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) < CURDATE()
        ) AS ExpiredWarrantyCount
    ,   (
            SELECT MAX( purchased )
            FROM   productWarranty
            WHERE  product = Base.product
        ) AS LastPurchased
FROM    (
            SELECT DISTINCT product
            FROM   productWarranty
        ) AS Base
```

Comment: Hi, at first thanks for your solution. It works great. I've tried to add a JOIN commant, because I would like to get the company name added to this table. But it isn't working. :-/ I tried to add it to the base query without success. Any ideas?

Comment: @emjay - I think you can find plenty of examples on how to use a JOIN ([this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), for example, or [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)). If you are still struggling, though, please post a new question. Stack Overflow is not a message board.

Comment: Okay, I made a SQL Fiddle, so i really should make a new Question? because it's just about extending your query with a join. I tried it, but it doesn't work. I don't know where to place it, i thought in the base query, but that doesn't work. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60396/1)