# How to handle large mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following query:

```
SELECT  p2c.pid AS productNumber,
        p.name AS productName
    ,   (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   products2customers
            WHERE  pid = p2c.pid
        ) AS registered
    ,   (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   products2customers
            WHERE  pid = p2c.pid
               AND date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) >= CURDATE()
        ) AS inWarranty
    ,   (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM   products2customers
            WHERE  pid = p2c.pid
               AND date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) < CURDATE()
        ) AS outOfWarranty
    ,   (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), '%d.%m.%Y')
            FROM   products2customers
            WHERE  pid = p2c.pid
        ) AS lastPurchased
    ,   (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT( date_add( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), '%d.%m.%Y')
            FROM   products2customers
            WHERE  pid = p2c.pid
        ) AS warrantyUntil
FROM    (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                p2c.pid
            FROM
                products2customers p2c
        ) AS p2c
JOIN
    products p
ON
    p.id = p2c.pid
ORDER BY
    inWarranty DESC
```

The query is executed on a database table, which has 25.000 rows. The execution time for this query is at about 40 secs. The results will be shown at a webpage, so it's not so great to wait 40secs for the result.

Is there a way, to execute this query and save it's output? Because it would be enough if this query is executed every night.

What's the best way for doing this? Should I create a cronjob and execute this query and write the result in a database? Or is there a better way?

Or can i optimize this query, to make it faster?

Comment: If realtime is not an issue you can use a [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) to run a query at set times, and `SELECT INTO` to create a new table with the output. You can then run queries on this new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all those correlated subqueries are killing you. Try this:

```
SELECT  p2c.pid AS productNumber,
        p.name AS productName,
        COUNT(*) AS registered,
        SUM(date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) >= CURDATE()) AS inWarranty,
        SUM(date_add(from_unixtime(purchased), INTERVAL 5 YEAR) < CURDATE()) AS outOfWarranty,
        DATE_FORMAT( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), '%d.%m.%Y') AS lastPurchased,
        DATE_FORMAT( date_add( MAX( from_unixtime(purchased) ), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), '%d.%m.%Y') AS warrantyUntil
FROM products2customers p2c
JOIN products p ON p.id = p2c.pid
GROUP BY p2c.pid
ORDER BY inWarranty DESC
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, nice to see my SQL God. ;-) Baaam, 254ms with your query. Thanks for helping me again. ;-) Could you please post this answer also in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496642/mysql-counting-rows-with-loop Because I think your solution is by far the best. :) Thanks and Greetings from Germany. ;-)

Comment: Hey @Barmar, it seems like outOfWarranty isn't counting right. I've compared my long query with yours and also checked the data in the table. Could you please check your answer?

Comment: Had `>=` where it should have been `<`.

Comment: Barmar, do you think it is possible to add one column "remainingDays" which count's the days from today to "outOfWarranty" ?

Comment: Of course. Use DATEDIFF to subtract NOW() from the warranty end date.

Answer (score 1):

maybe start off by doing an `Explain Plan` to see if any parts can be sped up by the creation of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Put this into a cron job:

```
CREATE TABLE products_warrany SELECT p2c.pid AS productNumber, ...
```

Later use the following query instead of original long one:

```
SELECT * FROM products_warrany ORDER BY ...
```

You also gain ability to run additional filtering, ordering and so forth. [Reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)